# Azure Devops pipeline getting error while running BUILD FAILED "Error: The process '/Users/runner/work/1/s/main/gradlew' failed with exit code 1"

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, pipeline

Android Azure Devops pipeline getting error while running BUILD FAILED **"Error: The process '/Users/runner/work/1/s/main/gradlew' failed with exit code 1"**

At locale system everything working and apk generated but when run pipeline at azure devops it showing the error

**Code analysis failed. Gradle exit code: -1. Error: Error: The process '/Users/runner/work/1/s/main/gradlew' failed with exit code 1**

I am already using Java 11.

Please help me out.

I searched a lot for the same but not get any solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you use self-hosted agent, you can try to manually build this project again. See if you have same error or not.

Comment: Yes, I am using self-hosted agent, I already tried building this project manually multiple time and it is working fine. but pipeline still not working.

Comment: If you can manually build this project on this agent, suggest check the parameter in this pipeline job. 
check the pipeline log, 
check pipeline execute build with some parameters.
then you can follow these build command and build manually again.

Comment: I got the solution for this issue and resolved it by making changes to Build Task instead of using buildDebug or buildRelease. I used build-task as build only